# python как заменить значения строк в двух разных файлах?

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, строки, сортировка

В общем есть два файла:

test1.txt

```
{
  "numbers":{
       "name": "petya",
        "weight": "1.3.5",
}
}
```

test2.conf

```
{
"things":{
      "colors": "red"
      "size": "4.5.7"   
}
```

Необходимо данные "вес" заминить во втором файле на "size" именно значение.
test2.conf

```
{
"things":{
      "colors": "red"
      "size": "1.3.5"   
}
```

Не могу разобраться как во втором файле найти нужное место и вписать туда данные из переменной.

Comment: Отформатируйте содержимое файлов

Comment: Что именно у вас не получается? Получить нужное значение из первого файла или записать его во второй?

Comment: значение первого я получил и записал в переменную, но не получается записать во второй файл в нужное место.

Comment: @tyrak найдите подстроку `'size'` в строке = файле

Comment: Перезапиши файл целиком. Json формат не поточный и не индексируемый - его перезаписывают целиком

Comment: Да извиняюсь я новичек, а как именно это сделать? или хотя бы что гуглить?)

Answer (score 0):

Смотри `json.load`, `json.dump`:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Смотри работу с файлами: `with open(...`

Comment: Так только один файл json. А второй нет. я так понял нужно переводить файл в строку и запоминать строку и положение в строке.

Comment: Не надо строк и положений. Надо прочитать 2 файла, распарсить. Получатся словари. Переложить значение из одного словаря в другой. И записать (dump) обратно в файл.